# Can I (an American) join my American boyfriend who works in Germany?

Tags: germany, immigration, resident-permit

My boyfriend and I are both Americans.  He maybe taking a job in Germany.  How can I accompany him there even though I'm not a spouse?

Comment: You can always visit. If however you want to live there, then you will have to look the myriad of ways you can go and become resident in Germany. Have you and your boyfriend been living together as partners? For how long?